# Neo4jPHP Transaction queries: getting errors in query construction

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I am trying to implement basic transaction based queries using Jadell's Neo4jPHP.

Here is my code:

```
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();
$query = new Query($client, "CREATE UNIQUE (u:users {email})-[r:visited {'time':'1425283200'}]->(e:halls {hallId}) RETURN r", array('email' => array('email' => 'test@test.com'), 'hallId' => array('hallId' => 1234)));
$result = $transaction->addStatements($query);
$transaction->commit();
```

I am getting an error:

> [message] => Invalid input ''': expected whitespace, a property key
>   name, '}', an identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 1, column
>   52)\n

Any clues as to what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following (removed parameters) and still getting an error:

```
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();
$query = new Query($client, "CREATE UNIQUE (u:users {'email':'" . $email . "'})-[r:visited]->(e:halls {'hallId':'" . $hallId . "'}) RETURN r");
$result = $transaction->addStatements($query);
$transaction->commit();
```

Getting an error:

> [message] => Unable to deserialize request: Can not deserialize
>   instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token\n

Comment: there is a : missing before the relationship type, it should be [:visited

Comment: That is a typo in the question... it is not an error in the way I am sending data.

Comment: ok. then 'time' should not be between single quotes as it is the property key, should just be time:

Comment: Please check my updated post ... I removed the time relationship property, and still getting an error, but a different one though.

Comment: If you echo out your query and try to send it using the neo4j console (http://localhost:8080 or wherever your server is) do you still get an error?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Use query parameters instead of string concatenation

```
$transaction = $client->beginTransaction();
$cypher="CREATE UNIQUE (u:users {email:{email}})-[r:visited]->(e:halls {hallId:{hallId}}) RETURN r";
$query = new Query($client,$cypher,array('email'=>$email,'hallId'=>$hallId));
$result = $transaction->addStatements($query);
$transaction->commit();
```